# How to redirect program error to a file while using pipes

Tags: shell-script, shell

I'm running a command on a Linux machine to backup my DB:

```
(echo "`date`: START DUMPING"; db_dump.sh; echo "`date`: DONE DUMPING") >>db_dump.log
```

And in the db_dump.sh:

```
pg_dump -v --dbname=mydb | pigz | openssl enc -aes128 -k ssecret -out db_dump.gz.aes
```

How would I catch the informative output from pg_dump, pigz and openssl to db_dump.log?

Currently I'm thinking doing it:

```
pg_dump -v --dbname=mydb 2>>db_dump.log| pigz 2>>db_dump.log| openssl enc -aes128 -k ssecret -out db_dump.gz.aes 2>>db_dump.log
```

but that seems quite cumbersome...

Comment: Don't you already get them from your first command? If you mean stderr, doesn't using the exact command you have there but also redirecting error work? I mean `(echo "`date`: START DUMPING"; db_dump.sh; echo "`date`: DONE DUMPING") >>db_dump.log 2>>&1`?

Comment: For some reason that didn't work. I ran the command as suggested and my nightly backup script apparently (from logs) just stopped and exited at that point. Also, it might not work anyway as it's not the db_dump.sh that's erroring but commands it would be running and those would be in a sub-shell..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try grouping with brackets:

```
( pg_dump -v --dbname=mydb | pigz | openssl enc -aes128 -k ssecret -out db_dump.gz.aes ) 2>>db_dump.log
```

Individual stderr output from all parts of the pipe will go into the same destination.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick!

Answer (score -1):

You can use below method

Program 2>filename